# Determining whether DBpedia resources are Cities or Countries

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I use DBpedia to extract information about airports with a given IATA code.  The query I'm using follows.  The results I'm getting include two rows for one airport;  in one the city is the location, and in the other, the country is the location.  How can I retrieve the type of the location (whether it's a city or country)? This is the query I'm using:

```
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT * WHERE { 
  ?subject rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Airport;
           rdfs:label ?label;
           dbpedia-owl:location ?location;
           dbpedia-owl:iataLocationIdentifier ?iata;
           geo:lat ?latitude;
           geo:long ?longitude.
  FILTER (lang(?label) = 'en' and regex(?iata, "MGQ"))
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20dbpprop%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia-owl%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20geo%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdf%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A?subject%20rdf%3atype%20dbpedia-owl%3aAirport;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3alocation%20?location;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3aiataLocationIdentifier%20?iata;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20geo%3alat%20?latitude;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20geo%3along%20?longitude.%0D%0AFILTER%20%28lang%28?label%29%20=%20%27en%27%20and%20regex%28?iata,%20%22MGQ%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, resources can have *lots* of types, because things have lots of values for the predicate `rdf:type`.  In this case, it sounds like you want to retrieve the associated city or country type, if one is present.  If you look at the resource http://dbpedia.org/resource/Somalia, you can see that it has the type `dbpedia-owl:Country`.  For http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mogadishu, there's no City type, but there is settlement, and that may be the most appropriate for identifying cities.

You can use `values` to specify a set of permissible values for a variable, and use `optional` to get some matches, if they're present.  E.g.,

```
select * where {
  ?subject rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Airport;
           rdfs:label ?label;
           dbpedia-owl:location ?location;
           dbpedia-owl:iataLocationIdentifier ?iata;
           geo:lat ?latitude;
           geo:long ?longitude.
  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?label),'en') && contains(?iata, "MGQ"))

  optional {
    values ?locationType { dbpedia-owl:Settlement dbpedia-owl:Country } 
    ?location a ?locationType
  }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://goo.gl/uiyo7G)

Also note that I've used `langMatches` to check language tags;  that's the proper way to do that.  Since the regular expression didn't do anything more than checking whether a substring occurred in a string, I've changed it to `contains`.

For what it's worth, I don't know whether I've used this `values` inside `optional` pattern before, but I rather like it, and I expect that it may be useful in the future.  It doesn't have the same effect to put the `values` *outside* the `optional`, because if you do that, then the `?locationType` always gets a value, it's just that the `optional` part might not match.  That is, if you take the `values` outside of the `optional`, you'll get four result rows:  2 locations × 2 locationTypes = 4 combinations.