# Retrieving the original order of RDF values for the same subject and predicate from DBpedia

Tags: rdf, dbpedia

If a subject has multiple objects (values) for the same predicate, it seems that their order is random. For instance:

Original data in Wikipedia for [Punta Cana Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punta_Cana_International_Airport):

```
Location    Punta Cana in La Altagracia Province, Dominican Republic
```

[Data in DBpedia](https://dbpedia.org/page/Punta_Cana_International_Airport) (dbo:location):

```
dbr:Dominican_Republic
dbr:Punta_Cana
dbr:La_Altagracia_Province
```

As you can see, the information is no longer ordered from the most detailed to the most general.

Initially I thought this would solve the problem:

[Determining whether DBpedia resources are Cities or Countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079636/determining-whether-dbpedia-resources-are-cities-or-countries)

Basically the accepted answer proposes checking the type of the location and looking for "dbo:settlement". This works well some of the time, but then there are cases where an airport has two location values of this type, e.g. Heathrow Airport does. On the other hand, Gbado Airport doesn't have a dbo:settlement, but has a dbo:city.

I think instead of handling all the different cases it'd be better to have a way to either:

1. retrieve the values in their original order OR
2. retrieve the original single value, i.e. "Punta Cana in La Altagracia Province, Dominican Republic"

Is either of these possible?

Comment: it's impossible to tget the order - the infobox data is automatically converted to a possible set of RDF triples, for the location for example for each Wikilink that occurs in the value a separate RDF triple is created. RDF itself is just a **set** of triples, i.e. there is no ordering at all

Comment: indeed, for place - as the common pattern for a location is from the most specific to the most generic place - you could try to find relations in between those locations, like city -> district -> country and then build the string manually in SPARQL - but as you recognized, the schema and data is rather heterogeneous. That query would also be cumbersome if not impossible via a single query to make a pairwise comparison among the locations to get the geospatial hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I suspected it would be like this, but I'm new to RDF so I thought maybe there's a way. I guess I'll try retrieving the location type and also settlement type and get as much data correct as I can. For the remaining cases maybe I'll be able to query the Wikipedia API and deduce some extra information from that.

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question, and especially its title, as you're not really looking for "the original order" but a particular order (in this case, a hierarchy of enclosing geopolitical location identifiers) that suits your later goals. (One more [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) for the list...)

Answer (score 0):

In relational DBMS of both RDF and SQL models, the order in which records (a/k/a triples, in RDF) are returned is not defined by the spec. Engines serving both models *tend* to return the results in the same order when the same query is re-executed -- but this is not required! Results (a/k/a solutions) may be in any order, and may change in each execution of the query.

What *could* be done in Wikipedia (and in DBpedia extractors) would be to say that "Punta Cana Airport" is in "Punta Cana" which is in "La Altagracia Province" which is in "Dominican Republic", and the query could be written to get that stack of triples, which might be in any order, but could be processed by human or code, to reorder them into an ordered stack.

Note that DBpedia *mostly* uses explicit statements, not inferences, so there may, and probably will eventually if not now, be data like this --

```
PREFIX  dbr:  http://dbpedia.org/resource/
PREFIX  dbo:  http://dbpedia.org/ontology/

dbr:Punta_Cana_International_Airport
   dbo:location  dbr:Dominican_Republic     , 
                 dbr:Punta_Cana             , 
                 dbr:La_Altagracia_Province .

dbr:Punta_Cana
   dbo:location  dbr:Dominican_Republic     , 
                 dbr:La_Altagracia_Province .

dbr:La_Altagracia_Province
   dbo:location  dbr:Dominican_Republic     .
```

Writing the query (or post processor) to handle reduction of the nesting to a single staircase is left as an exercise for the reader (or at least, another question).